# Showing and hiding items with show more and show less buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a system for a photo section of my website that has a show more and hide less function, but I seem to be having a bit of trouble. I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SrK88/) so you can see exactly what I'm talking about.

Basically, I would like ten images the show on load (this is not happening) and then be able to show ten more and then have another button that would hide ten of them.

There seems to be something happening with my incrementing though. On load all the images are showing and when I hit show less then they all disappear. I can then add or remove ten, **but when there happens to be an uneven number of images it breaks and will hide or show more then is needed**. Does that make sense?

My js looks like this. Any help would be wonderful!

```
 size_li = $(".imgLinks li").size();
      x=10;
      $('.imgLinks li:lt('+x+')').show();
      $('.show_button').click(function () {
          x= (x+10 <= size_li) ? x+10 : size_li;
          $('.imgLinks li:lt('+x+')').show();
           $('.hide_button').show();
          if(x == size_li){
              $('.show_button').hide();
          }
      });
      $('.hide_button').click(function () {
          x=(x-10<0) ? 10 : x-10;
          $('.imgLinks li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
          $('.show_button').show();
           $('.hide_button').show();
          if(x == 10){
              $('.hide_button').hide();
          }
      });
```

Comment: You might want to rewrite `x=(x-10<0) ? 10 : x - 10` to `x = Math.max(x - 10, 0)` and `x= (x+10 <= size_li) ? x+10 : size_li` to `x = Math.min(x + 10, size_li)`

Comment: @user1561072 when I did that in the fiddle, it broke the whole thing...

Comment: Sorry for that, should be `x = Math.max(x - 10, 10)` and `Math.min(x + 10, size_li)`. Are you sure about `(x-10<0)` but the minimum of `10`? EDIT: Tried it, works.

Comment: @user1561072, that still breaks it. :) and my view is set up to view ten at a time. It could be less though, but I'm assuming then the hide and show wont be an option at all.

Comment: If that's the case, I am still sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hide all images and the hide button initially, your js code will show first ten and everything seems fine. Add the following in your css code,

```
.imgLinks li, .hide_button{
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SrK88/8/

or add these two lines at the top of your js,

```
$(".imgLinks li").hide();
$(".hide_button").hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SrK88/9

**EDIT**

For the even/uneven issue modify the code for hiding as so,

```
$('.hide_button').click(function () {
        x = (x - 10 < 0) ? 10 : (x%10!=0?x-(x%10):x - 10);
        $('.imgLinks li').not(':lt(' + x + ')').hide();
        $('.show_button').show();
        $('.hide_button').show();
        if (x == 10) {
            $('.hide_button').hide();
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SrK88/24/

Comment: This does fix part of it, and thank you, but there is still the issue if the li's are not even. Say instead of 20 images there are 18. If on that fiddle you go all the way to the bottom you can see what it does.

Comment: @zazvorniki missed that part, i think now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can follow this [`example`](http://jsfiddle.net/jn8VW/3/). Basically it's slicing 2 items instead of 10. It uses css to hide all li starting from the 3rd li inside ul.

Comment: I was looking at this, but I went with what I did because it made more sense with my application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about this http://jsfiddle.net/SrK88/21/

**UPDATE** 
chagned the code to handle uneven amounts using the `%` operator: http://jsfiddle.net/SrK88/23/

First your images were all visible because you never hide them to begin with.

in your size bit I changed it to `var size_li = $(".imgLinks li").hide().size();`

the rest I would be happy to explain if it isn';t clear from the example

It seemed overly complicated to internally track where you were in the showing/hiding so instead I just look at the visible `<li>`'s and check whether you can show or hide more

Comment: This does work, but it's still having the issue with the uneven showing and hiding. For example if there are 18 images instead of twenty overall then when I go to hide them it hides them unevenly.

Comment: you could add a check when all are visible to figure out what to utilizing the % operator (i.e: 79 % 10 = 9)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your saying... Also in my code this forces them to have a style of display:list-item; I'm not really sure where that is coming from.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Except it seems that this is turning my display:inline; li's to display: list-item;. Any idea why?

Comment: not sure, I don't have that problem in Chrome, but I imagine it has to do with how jquery show/hide methods work, you can try using a "hide" class instead of directly messing with the display style: http://jsfiddle.net/SrK88/27/

Comment: I did some more testing and it seemed to be how the visible reacted with the li's in safari and firefox because I don't actually have them as inline like I though, but inline-block.